# Dynamically naming captured groups in regex

Tags: regex, regex-group

I'm trying to name the captured groups of a long string based on a group previously matched. The keys and values matched all appear after the word `info`

For instance in this string:
`info user alice age seven`
I want to capture `alice` and name it `user` and capture `seven` and name it `age`.

The keys user and age are dynamic and could change each time, and I need that to be reflected accurately on the captured group's name.

essentially, I need to extend this regex to be dynamic.
`info\s(?<user>\w+\b)`

Is this possible?

I'm aware there is a limitation on regex to have unlimited groups, so in this case, just assume there are only ever two groups that need to be matched

Answer (score 2):

**Note**: group names are *static*, they cannot be assigned at runtime.

You can only specify the group names inside the pattern, like

```
info\s+user\s+(?<user>\w+)\s+age\s+(?<age>\w+(?:-\w+)?)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CCZcHy/3/). *Details*:

- `info\s+user\s+` - `info` string, then one or more whitespace, `user`, one or more whitespaces
- `(?<user>\w+)` - Group "user": one or more word chars
- `\s+age\s+` - `age` enclosed with one or more whitespaces
- `(?<age>\w+(?:-\w+)?)` - Group "age": one or more word chars and an optional occurrence of `-` and one or more word chars. Note the `(?:-\w+)?` is added to account for `seventy-four` or `seventy-five`, etc.

Comment: Ah so this is close, but what I meant is how can I make user and age dynamic? For instance, I'd like this string to be matched as well : ````info name alice height seven```` where alice would be in the captured group "name" and "seven" would be in the captured group "height"

Comment: @testing495 Group names are *static*, they cannot be assigned at runtime. However, you may post-process matche with code. That means, if you need a dynamic "enough" solution, you need to provide language tag.

Comment: I'm using this regex to parse logs for fluent bit. This issue is the assigning of the group names at runtime, so I guess what I'm trying to do is impossible. thanks for your help tho!

Comment: @testing495 Right, in that case, you can probably just use several regexps instead of one.